# How to decrypt hash get from this function

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

we are encrypting our password in the app using this function.How to decrypt them when we need actual string.`var crypto = require('crypto');`

```
function encryptPassword(password) {
    var salt = new Buffer('priotzen', 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It's a one-way hash. It's not possible to decrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided generates a one-way hash. If you use this, then you validate passwords by comparing hashed values. There is no way to decrypt the existing password. If the user forgets their password, then you do a password reset.

If you really want to have retrievable passwords, then you need to look at encryption rather than hashing algorithms. For this type of application, symmetric key encryption, such as AES may be suitable.

Keep in mind that encryption is computationally much more expensive than hashing, and less secure. Hashing is nearly always preferred for passwords. Unless there is some extremely compelling reason to have retrievable passwords, you should steer your client towards one-way hash passwords.

Comment: 1. Encryption should not be used when password verification is the goal. 2. Encryption may not be more expensive than hashing given that CPUs with AES-NI instructions are commonly available and many platforms have fast crypto engines available. 3. PBKDF2 is a NIST recommended method for password verifiers. Hashing, actually **iterated cryptographic hashing**, is the preferred method for creating password verifiers used for password verification. 4. Encryption of passwords can lead to the exposing of the passwords to attackers and admin personal.